# Declare specific class names in styled components

Tags: javascript, styled-components

maybe there is obvious information, but I wasn't able to find it. I want to render specific classNames for a styled-components, for example: `page--title` for testing by selectors.

Is there a solution without declaring `className` on every tag? Could someone help with some hints?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
const PageTitle = styled.h1.attrs({
  className: 'page--title'
})
```

Comment: There is also a babel plugin that names the classnames like the components, that is also good for testing.